# ActionScript 3 and camelcase package name

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, syntax, compiler-errors, flash-builder

I'm using Flash Builder 4 to build my AIR application.

For a certain reason, I need to declare my package name in camelcase, and class names in lowercase:

```
//test.as
package Core { 
   public class test {
   }
}
```

The folder structure is like this (the dir 'Core' matches the package name):

```
src/
  Core/
    test.as
```

However, Flash Builder shows error and it doesn't compile at all, only when I put the package name as 'core' then it compiles.

Does AS3 syntax allow uppercase letters in package name? Or just because Flash Builder implicitly disallows this?

Comment: I don't know whether it allows on not, but the best practices are to name your packages lowercase and your classes uppercase. You should follow them anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS3 syntax disallow upper case first letter in package name. But you can use org.myCompany for example

Comment: have you got the syntax specification about this package name naming rule?

Comment: The naming standard for a package is called "lower camelcase" whereas class naming standards are called "upper camelcase"

Answer (score 1):

I just tried making a package 'Core' and it compiled fine.
What I suspect is that you are working on Windows and that the name of the package is not maching (case wise) with the folder on disk. i.e. you probably have a folder named 'core' while the name of the package is 'Core'.
Windows would make it hard to switch cases of folder name without changing the name, so you can rename 'core' to 'core1' and then 'core1' to 'Core'.

Anyway, all this is based on the hypothesis that there is a mismatch :) (yes, I saw that you have explicitly mentioned the folder structure....but I think you might have missed the case)